# Rewriting summation formula

Tags: summation

I just watched a tutorial on recurrence by substitution. In the tutorial, it mentioned about rewriting

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^\mathbb{k}{2^i}$

as (2<sup>k+1</sup> - 2). My question is can I generalize it as x<sup>limit + 1</sup> - x where x is the base.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $S = \sum_{i=1}^k x^i$. Consider the following manipulation $$S = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^k = x(1 + x + \cdots + x^{k-1}) = x(S + 1 - x^k)$$
It follows that $S = (x^{k+1} - x)/(x - 1)$

Answer (score 6):

Nice observation and almost true:
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^\mathbb{n}{a^i} = \frac{a^{n+1}-a}{a-1}
$$
It's a special case of a [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Comment: As an example, $\sum_{i=1}^5 10^i=\frac{10^6-10}9$, which the OP should verify by evaluating each side.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$a(n)=b^n$$
for some $b$; then
$$\Delta a(n)=a(n+1)-a(n)=b^{n+1}-b^n=b^n(b-1);$$
divide both sides by $b-1$:
$$b^n=\frac{\Delta a(n)}{b-1};$$
substitute back for $a(n)$:
$$a(n)=b^n=\frac{\Delta (b^n)}{b-1}={\large\Delta}\left(\frac{b^n}{b-1}\right).$$
Evaluate
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^na(k).$$
Apply the fundamental theorem of discrete calculus:
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^na(k)=\bigg({\large\Delta}^{-1}a(k)\bigg)\Bigg|_{k=1}^{n+1}=\left(\frac{b^k}{b-1}\right)\Bigg|_{k=1}^{n+1}=\frac{b^{k+1}}{b-1}-\frac{b}{b-1};$$
write out the answer:
$$\therefore\sum\limits_{k=1}^nb^k=\frac{b^{k+1}-b}{b-1}.$$